# How to access Bonita Engine API from a custom REST API Extension

Tags: bonita

I would like to develop a [REST API Extensions](http://documentation.bonitasoft.com/product-bos-sp/rest-api-extensions) that access the Engine API in order to do some queries and then start a new process.

What is the best way to access the Engine API from such REST extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Bonita BPM 7.2 you can use `context.apiClient`to access Bonita BPM Engine APIs from your REST API extension Groovy code.

For example in order to use the `IdentityAPI` simply use `context.apiClient.identityAPI` followed by the method you want to call: `context.apiClient.identityAPI.getUsers(0, 10, UserCriterion.FIRST_NAME_ASC)`